# Hibernate 4.1.x EhCache doesn't store anything on disk

Tags: hibernate, caching, spring-mvc, ehcache, nhibernate-caches

I'm using **Hibernate 4.1.1.Final** with **Spring MVC 3.1.x** and using both **first and second level cache**. I configured my domain objects using annotations for cache operations. But cache doesn't store anything on the disk.

**Here's my ehcache.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

    <!--
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    -->
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache"/>
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
        eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120" 
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000" 
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
    />
</ehcache>
```

**Hibernate Cache Properties:**

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
```

**Annonation-based configuration for domain objects:**

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

**No folder named **ehcache** in the /tmp folder:**

[image: /tmp folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EhCache will store objects on to disk only when it has saved `maxElementsInMemory` number of objects in the memory itself. Are you sure that this much number of objects are really getting cached because only after this point, EhCache will start storing objects on the disk.